# Text aligning and overflow

Tags: css

I'm having a lot of trouble with aligning some text and an overflow problem.  I originally was floating my list items to the left but that was giving me issues with vertical alignment of text.  So I switched to display as inline-block.  The problem I'm having now though is that I simply can't get my second label to line up (sort of like a second column) with the first label.  I realize that's probably because I'm setting it up as an inline-block but I'm essentially looking for two things;  1) I'd like the second label to align right next to the first label and not overflow, and 2) make sure the vertical alignment of the second label's text is at the bottom.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<ol>
<li>
<label class="lbl">What market changes are you trying to capture?</label>
<label class="val">test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3</label>
</li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
body 
{
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    font:11px verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}

fieldset 
{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:1em;
    padding:1em;  
    width: 75%;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

fieldset ol
{
    list-style:none;
}

fieldset li
{

    display:inline-block;    
    margin-bottom:1em;
    width:100%;
}

fieldset label.lbl
{   
    display:inline-block; 
    width:26%;
    margin-right:1em;
    text-align:justify;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

fieldset label.val
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CDsLr/2/

Comment: I don't quite understand. You have a label with a class "val" (implying "value") that seems to contain values. I think you're using the wrong kind of element(s) to start with, unless I'm missing something. Labels are usually used in forms and are associated with an input. Here I see fieldsets that contain just list items..?

Comment: You have to specify the width of `fieldset label.val` to make this work.

Comment: Hi Greg.  Please see my reply to Billy below.  Yes I'm aware I'm using labels inside the fieldset.  Perhaps that's not good practice? But I have my reasons for doing this, mostly for formatting and appearance.

Comment: @nwellnhof, yes I just tried that and it looks like the max width it can go is 70% before pushing below the first label ("stacking" as Billy described below).  However, my vertical-align set to bottom still does nothing.

Comment: @mseg Please explain clearly what you want in your post(I mean the things you discussed in the comments below). I will try my best to achieve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are aiming for, but taking a wild stab in the dark (how I would lay it out maybe)

```
label{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

***N.B. The point is to float all of the elements left, not just one, and also to specify a width explicitly, where they can both fit side by side rather than stacking.***

### http://jsfiddle.net/CDsLr/3/

Comment: Billy, sorry for the confusing post.  I wasn't sure how to best explain it.  You're sort of on the right track here but the problem with your approach is that I can't vertically align the "val" label to the bottom.  I just noticed I had it as middle.  My mistake. I meant it to say bottom.  Changing just that property to bottom now using your code does nothing.  I need to be able to accomplish that as well.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different point of view: since you're not using inputs, I am going to assume that what's going on is that this is a "confirmation" or other sort of visual feedback page. The user supplied an answer, and now you're echoing back what their answer was.

If that's a false assumption, it might be (but won't necessarily be!) helpful to know the overall goal.

Swapping out the labels for plain old list items, here's what I came up with [EDIT: got rid of some crufty CSS]:

http://jsfiddle.net/CDsLr/6/

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <ol>
        <li class="lbl">What market changes are you trying to capture?</li>
        <li class="val">test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3test
            123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3test 123 test 123test 3</li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```css
body 
{
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    font:11px verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}

fieldset 
{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:1em;
    padding:1em;  
    width: 75%;
}

fieldset ol
{
    list-style:none;
}

fieldset li
{
    display:inline-block;    
    margin-bottom:1em;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

fieldset .lbl
{   
    width:26%;
    margin-right:1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is this on the right track?

Comment: updated to a slightly newer version that gets rid of a few CSS redundancies and unecessary rules.

Comment: Gregg, yes it's on the right track but there is one thing missing and I guess I need to be perfectly specific; using your example, I'd like the "val" text to begin and align at the 'last' line of the "lbl" text.  I thought the vertical-align: bottom property would accomplish that but it doesn't.  I've read up on that and I guess this property is useful in specific context.  Please let me know if you still need further clarification.

Comment: OK, so the first line of "val" needs to be aligned with the last line of "lbl". That's an interesting use case... be curious to know how it pans out from a UI perspective. I'll give it a try, but... there's no CSS property that will "just do this", probably because it's not really considered a layout best practice. (Incidentally, I dropped your justified text, too... just for my own sanity. It looks much better to my eye, but if you insist on it, you'll have to add it back!)

Comment: Greg, you made me laugh about the justified text.  Yes that came as a "suggestion" from a colleague of mine and I may not keep it. :)  As for the use case, I can understand why it's difficult.  If it proves to be too much then I'll leave it as be.  I think it was asked to me for readability and formatting reasons.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CDsLr/7/ -- it's a hack that's proof of concept. I know that I have 3 lines of "lbl" text, so I make the "val" shift down 3*line height. You could do something like this dynamically with JavaScript. Note it also exceeds the fieldset because of the positioning.

Comment: For "readability and formatting" by far the more common and easy to read practice is the one demonstrated in the original fiddle. It's a pattern people expect to see for side-by-side Q&A. Otherwise, you should stack them above one another, which is another perfectly valid way to do it. The alignment like the "proof of concept" I just made is not intuitive. Sometimes developers have to put on our "designer" and "UX expert" hats, too, and convince the stakeholders that... well... their idea isn't right for the job.

Comment: Hmm. I can see where this is leading to then.  Unfortunately I don't think I'll be able to use this as I have similar questions that follow this.  However, I can definitely take some of the tips offered on this post and use them.  I think I'm good for now. Thanks so much Greg and to all those for their input!

Comment: Absolutely agree Greg!  Thanks!